# Amcharts grouping minute-time based data on one daily chunk no matter the selected zoom or axis granularity

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a problem with Amcharts,

I have four totally independent minute-separated data that corresponds to some simulated sensors, and configured the axes to have a resolution for even seconds, but it just groups alt the data at 00:00 as the pictures shows.

How could I solve it?

I dont think it has to be with granularity, since even when all points are displayed on the same datetime value, they are all displayed, so it is not about them being grouped together, but about them being wrongly set.

[image]
[image]

---

Here is my data generator python code

```
    import random as rd
    import datetime as dt

    archivo = open("data.js","w")

    dataFormat = '''{{
    \t"deviceID": {0},
    \t"name": "dev{0}",
    \t"value": {1},
    \t"timeStamp": "{2}",
    \t"color": "red",
    \t"raw": {3},
    \t"key-type": "posicion {3}"
    }}'''

    '''
    0: dev ID
    1: valor medido
    2: timestamp
    3: gr id
    '''
    primero = True

    devices = [1,2,3,4]
    grupos = [1,2,3]
    mediciones = 500
    minute = 0

    dateFormat = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ" 
    timeStamp =  dt.datetime.strptime("2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",dateFormat)

    archivo.write("data = [")

    for device in devices:
        timeStamp = timeStamp + dt.timedelta(minutes = rd.randint(20,30))
        for medicion in range(1,mediciones):
            if rd.randint(0,20)>3:
                if (not primero): 
                    archivo.write(",")
                primero = False
                timeStamp = timeStamp + dt.timedelta(minutes = rd.randint(5,10))
                lastDevice = ""
                newDevice = ""
                while newDevice == lastDevice:
                    newDevice = rd.choice(devices)
                archivo.write(dataFormat.format(newDevice, rd.randint(30,100), timeStamp.strftime(dateFormat), rd.choice(grupos)))
                lastDevice = newDevice
    archivo.write("]")
    archivo.close()
```

---

this is the amchart code

```js
data = [{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 63,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T00:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T00:44:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 72,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T00:54:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:01:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 76,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:11:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:18:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 40,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 97,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 61,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:43:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 35,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 30,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:58:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 73,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 42,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:09:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 90,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:15:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 86,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 69,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:25:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:33:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 55,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:40:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:49:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 39,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:58:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 50,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:04:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 86,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:30:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 44,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:46:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:51:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 34,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 83,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:09:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 32,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:18:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 58,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 68,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:35:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:41:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 98,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:49:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 69,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:56:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 52,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 88,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 34,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 60,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:37:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 66,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:44:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 64,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 96,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:05:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 46,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:11:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 32,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:17:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 54,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:22:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 49,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:35:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 51,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 33,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:52:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 65,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:00:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 84,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:05:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 81,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 87,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:17:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 85,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:23:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 94,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:33:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 73,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:39:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 93,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 84,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 75,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 53,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:07:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 98,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:13:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 40,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:22:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 83,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:31:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 77,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 91,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:48:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 96,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:54:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 87,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 99,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:05:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 49,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 90,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:30:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 52,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:40:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 66,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 96,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 54,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:58:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 35,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:09:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 94,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:17:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 61,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:26:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 46,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:36:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 91,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 68,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:56:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 61,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:01:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:11:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 60,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:18:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 76,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:25:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 66,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:32:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 57,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:40:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 92,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:55:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 40,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:19:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:24:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:30:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 53,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:39:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 69,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:47:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 71,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:52:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
}]

    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    var chart = am4core.create("divStockPrices", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.padding(0, 15, 0, 15);
    chart.colors.step = 3;

    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

    let msje = `
    <center><strong><a href=LINK>NAME</a> {categoryX}</strong></center>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Value</th>
            <td>ACTUAL%</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />`

    function prepareData(data) {
        let datas = {};
        datas.length = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let miBool = false;
            ids = Object.keys(datas)
            for (let j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                if (data[i].deviceID == ids[j]) miBool = true;
            }
            if (!miBool) {
                datas[data[i].deviceID] = [data[i]]
                datas.length += 1;
            } else datas[data[i].deviceID].push(data[i])
        }
        return datas;
    }

    var quantity = 1000;

    let data2 = prepareData(data);

    //chart.data = data2;
    // the following line makes value axes to be arranged vertically.
    chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";

    // uncomment this line if you want to change order of axes
    //chart.bottomAxesContainer.reverseOrder = true;

    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.1;
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
    dateAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;
    dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.99;
    dateAxis.keepSelection = true;
    
    dateAxis.baseInterval = {
        "timeUnit": "minute",
        "count": 1
    };
    dateAxis.groupIntervals.setAll([
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 5 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 10 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 15 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 30 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 3 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 6 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 12 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 2 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 3 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 4 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 5 },
        { timeUnit: "week", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 2 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 3 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 6 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 2 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 5 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 10 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 50 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 100 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 200 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 500 }
        ]);

    dateAxis.groupData = true;

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
    // height of axis
    valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(65);

    valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fill = am4core.color("#000000");
    valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
    valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.padding(2, 2, 2, 2);

    //valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
    valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em"

    let series = []
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        series.push(chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries()));
        series[i].dataFields.dateX = "timeStamp";
        series[i].dataFields.valueY = "value";
        //series[i].dataFields.valueYShow = "changePercent";
        //series[i].tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.changePercent.formatNumber('[#0c0]+#.00|[#c00]#.##|0')}%";
        series[i].name = "Stock A";
        series[i].tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
        series[i].tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
        series[i].tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
        series[i].tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 2;
        series[i].tooltip.label.fill = series[i].stroke;
        series[i].data = data2[i];
        series[i].tensionX = 0.9;

        let bullet = series[i].bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());

        // Maneja el texto a mostrar cuando se posa el mouse encima
        bullet.tooltipHTML = msje.replace('ACTUAL', "{value}").replace('LINK', "").replace('NAME', "{name}");

        // Modifica el marcador para ser un circulo con el formato especificado
        let circle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Circle);
        circle.width = 3;
        circle.height = 3;
        circle.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        circle.verticalCenter = "middle";
        circle.stroke = am4core.color("#999999");
        circle.strokeWidth = 2;
        circle.fill = am4core.color("{color}");
    }

    function customizeGrip(grip) {
        grip.icon.disabled = true;
        grip.background.disabled = true;
    }

    var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        scrollbarX.series.push(series[i]);
    }
    customizeGrip(scrollbarX.startGrip);
    customizeGrip(scrollbarX.endGrip);
    scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
    var sbSeries = scrollbarX.scrollbarChart.series.getIndex(0);
    sbSeries.dataFields.valueYShow = undefined;
    chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
```

```html
<style> 
    .graphContainer  {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    
#chartdata {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

</style>

<script> let TargetID = 2; </script>

<script src="node_modules/ng"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/piechart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div class = "graphContainer" id="divStockPrices"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, AmCharts parses `yyyy-MM-dd` dates without the timestamps. You need to modify the chart dateFormatter's `inputDateFormat` property to match your date+timestamp format, as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/#Parsing_dates). Since you're using an ISO format, `'i'` will suffice.

```
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = 'i';
```

Updated code below:

```js
data = [{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 63,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T00:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T00:44:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 72,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T00:54:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:01:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 76,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:11:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:18:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 40,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 97,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 61,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:43:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 35,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 30,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T01:58:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 73,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 42,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:09:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 90,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:15:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 86,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 69,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:25:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:33:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 55,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:40:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:49:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 39,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T02:58:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 50,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:04:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 86,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:30:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 44,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:46:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:51:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 34,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T03:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 83,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:09:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 32,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:18:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 58,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 68,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:35:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:41:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 98,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:49:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 69,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T04:56:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 52,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 88,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 34,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 60,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:37:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 66,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:44:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 64,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 96,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T05:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:05:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 46,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:11:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 32,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:17:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 54,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:22:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:28:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 49,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:35:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 51,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 33,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T06:52:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 65,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:00:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 84,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:05:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 81,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 87,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:17:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 85,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:23:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 94,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:33:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 73,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:39:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 93,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 84,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 75,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T07:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 53,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:07:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 98,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:13:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 40,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:22:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 83,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:31:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 77,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:38:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 91,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:48:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 96,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:54:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 87,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T08:59:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 99,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:05:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 49,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 90,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:20:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 38,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:30:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 52,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:40:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 66,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 96,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 54,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T09:58:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 35,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:09:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 94,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:17:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 61,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:26:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 46,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:36:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 91,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:50:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 68,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T10:56:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 61,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:01:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:11:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 60,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:18:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 2,
    "name": "dev2",
    "value": 76,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:25:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 66,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:32:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 57,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:40:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 92,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:45:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T11:55:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 40,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:03:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 67,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:10:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 4,
    "name": "dev4",
    "value": 45,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:19:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 3,
    "key-type": "posicion 3"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 78,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:24:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 31,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:30:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 53,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:39:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 1,
    "name": "dev1",
    "value": 69,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:47:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 2,
    "key-type": "posicion 2"
},{
    "deviceID": 3,
    "name": "dev3",
    "value": 71,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-01T12:52:00.000Z",
    "color": "red",
    "raw": 1,
    "key-type": "posicion 1"
}]

    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    var chart = am4core.create("divStockPrices", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.padding(0, 15, 0, 15);
    chart.colors.step = 3;
    chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = 'i';

    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

    let msje = `
    <center><strong><a href=LINK>NAME</a> {categoryX}</strong></center>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Value</th>
            <td>ACTUAL%</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />`

    function prepareData(data) {
        let datas = {};
        datas.length = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let miBool = false;
            ids = Object.keys(datas)
            for (let j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                if (data[i].deviceID == ids[j]) miBool = true;
            }
            if (!miBool) {
                datas[data[i].deviceID] = [data[i]]
                datas.length += 1;
            } else datas[data[i].deviceID].push(data[i])
        }
        return datas;
    }

    var quantity = 1000;

    let data2 = prepareData(data);

    //chart.data = data2;
    // the following line makes value axes to be arranged vertically.
    chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";

    // uncomment this line if you want to change order of axes
    //chart.bottomAxesContainer.reverseOrder = true;

    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.1;
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
    dateAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;
    dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.99;
    dateAxis.keepSelection = true;
    
    dateAxis.baseInterval = {
        "timeUnit": "minute",
        "count": 1
    };
    dateAxis.groupIntervals.setAll([
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 5 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 10 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 15 },
        { timeUnit: "minute", count: 30 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 3 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 6 },
        { timeUnit: "hour", count: 12 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 2 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 3 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 4 },
        { timeUnit: "day", count: 5 },
        { timeUnit: "week", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 2 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 3 },
        { timeUnit: "month", count: 6 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 1 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 2 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 5 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 10 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 50 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 100 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 200 },
        { timeUnit: "year", count: 500 }
        ]);

    dateAxis.groupData = true;

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
    // height of axis
    valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(65);

    valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fill = am4core.color("#000000");
    valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
    valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.padding(2, 2, 2, 2);

    //valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
    valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em"

    let series = []
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        series.push(chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries()));
        series[i].dataFields.dateX = "timeStamp";
        series[i].dataFields.valueY = "value";
        //series[i].dataFields.valueYShow = "changePercent";
        //series[i].tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.changePercent.formatNumber('[#0c0]+#.00|[#c00]#.##|0')}%";
        series[i].name = "Stock A";
        series[i].tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
        series[i].tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
        series[i].tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
        series[i].tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 2;
        series[i].tooltip.label.fill = series[i].stroke;
        series[i].data = data2[i];
        series[i].tensionX = 0.9;

        let bullet = series[i].bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());

        // Maneja el texto a mostrar cuando se posa el mouse encima
        bullet.tooltipHTML = msje.replace('ACTUAL', "{value}").replace('LINK', "").replace('NAME', "{name}");

        // Modifica el marcador para ser un circulo con el formato especificado
        let circle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Circle);
        circle.width = 3;
        circle.height = 3;
        circle.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        circle.verticalCenter = "middle";
        circle.stroke = am4core.color("#999999");
        circle.strokeWidth = 2;
        circle.fill = am4core.color("{color}");
    }

    function customizeGrip(grip) {
        grip.icon.disabled = true;
        grip.background.disabled = true;
    }

    var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        scrollbarX.series.push(series[i]);
    }
    customizeGrip(scrollbarX.startGrip);
    customizeGrip(scrollbarX.endGrip);
    scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
    var sbSeries = scrollbarX.scrollbarChart.series.getIndex(0);
    sbSeries.dataFields.valueYShow = undefined;
    chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
```

```html
<style> 
    .graphContainer  {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    
#chartdata {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

</style>

<script> let TargetID = 2; </script>

<script src="node_modules/ng"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/piechart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div class = "graphContainer" id="divStockPrices"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I never thought on looking the formattin page, I'll suggest Amchart team to mention this struggle on DateAxis page too.
Thanks again!